# How to send sensitive data through an email?

Tags: privacy

Many times I have been in situation where I needed to send something sensitive, like my personal data, medical report, or something else over the email.

In my country governmental institutions do not support or offer PGP encryption when sensitive data is transmitted.

How can I protect my documents? Any ideas?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117067/best-practices-for-sending-tax-data-to-and-from-a-tax-professional/117070#117070

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general sense, you can't - if it is attached in readily usable form. However, if you can communicate a password out-of-band (perhaps by a phone call), and the recipient is willing to unzip your documents, you could send them in an encrypted zip file. Be aware, though, that some email filters will delete any zip files that they can't open, and that once the data has been unzipped, it may well be sitting around on someone's computer.

It's very hit and miss as to what companies will accept though.

Comment: Change the extension to "piz" and it usually goes through :)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Yeah, but if they've got "Hide known extensions" turned on, good luck getting them to rename it back!